# Ninject error on WithConstructorArgument: No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

In a C# solution, I have the following Ninject set-up, a factory class that looks like this:

```
public class NinjectFactory : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectFactory()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        var bindings = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType == typeof(NinjectModule))
            .Select(t => (INinjectModule)Activator.CreateInstance(t))
            .ToArray();
        this.kernel.Load(bindings);
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType == null
            ? null
            : (IHttpController)kernel.Get(controllerType);
    }

    public T GetBinding<T>() where T : class
    {
        return kernel.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

and a number of Ninject modules, like so:

```
public class ModuleA: NinjectModule
{
    Bind<ILogging>().To<Logging>().InSingletonScope();
    Bind<IMapping>().To<Mapping>();
    ....
    ....
}

public class ModuleB: NinjectModule
{
    Bind<IDbTools>().To<DbTools>().InSingletonScope();
    ....
    ....
}
```

I also have the following two classes I am trying to inject in a third class:

```
public class ClassA : ISomeInterface
{
    private readonly IDbTools dbTools;
    private readonly IMapping mapping;
}

public class ClassB : ISomeInterface
{
    private readonly IDbTools dbTools;
    private readonly IMapping mapping;
}
```

The class I am injecting into looks like this:

```
public class SaveClass : ISaving
{
    private readonly IDbTools dbTools;
    private readonly IMapping mapping;
    private ISomeInterface classA;
    private ISomeInterface classB;

    public SaveClass(IDbTools dbTools, IMapping mapping, ISomeInterface classA, ISomeInterface classB)
    {
        ....
    }
```

The complexity of this issue arises from the fact there are two dependencies of the same type, i.e. ISomeInterface, in class SaveClass. When I try to inject them using the "WithConstructorArgument" keyword, i get the error "No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable." The error is happening in the following Ninject module class:

```
public class ModuleC : NinjectModule
{
    this.Bind<ISomeInterface>().To<ClassA>().InRequestScope().Named("ClassA");
    this.Bind<ISomeInterface>().To<ClassB>().InRequestScope().Named("ClassB");

    this.Bind<ISaving>().<SaveClass>().InRequestScope()
    .WithConstructorArgument("classA", Kernel.Get<ISomeInterface>("ClassA"))
    .WithConstructorArgument("classB", Kernel.Get<ISomeInterface>("ClassB"));

}
```

The exact error message is:

> {"Error activating IDbTools
>   No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
>   Activation path:
>     2) Injection of dependency IDbTools into parameter dbTools of constructor of type ClassA
>     1) Request for ISomeInterface
>
> Suggestions:
>     1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IDbTools.
>     2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
>     3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
>     4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
>     5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
>   "}

What is the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to pass the first two constructor arguments as well? IDbTools and IMapping? Looks like you are just passing the two ISomeInterface arguments when binding SaveClass to ISaveClass

Comment: No, the way WithConstuctorArgument works is any constructor arguments that are not specifically assigned values to get injected according to whatever bindings are set for them.

Comment: The error message indicates that the IDbTools binding is missing. Are you sure that it has been bound before ISomeInterface is requested?